# How to use triple INNER JOIN with one empty table?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Given is the following table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE projects
(
    project_id integer,
    name character varying(50),
    owner_user integer NOT NULL,
    owner_org integer NOT NULL,
)
```

A project can be either owned by a **user** (`user_id`), OR by an organization (`org_id`) So either field is 0. So I do an INNER JOIN on `projects`, `users`, and `organizations`, but if the project is owned by a user (and currently no organization does exist at all), the result is empty.

**Does NOT work**

```sql
SELECT *
FROM users u, projects p, organizations o
WHERE (p.owner_org != 0 AND o.org_id = p.owner_org) OR
      (p.owner_user != 0 AND u.user_id = p.owner_user);
```

Can anyone help me out? If I leave out `organization`, the result is 1 row, as expected.

**Works**

```sql
SELECT *
FROM projects p, users u
WHERE (p.owner_user != 0 AND u.user_id = p.owner_user);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Learn to use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.

You seem to want:

```
select *
from projects p left join
     users u 
     on p.owner_org = o.org_id left join
     organizations o
     on p.owner_user = u.user_id ;
```

I assume there is no id of `0` in the `projects` or `organizations` tables so the filtering is not necessary.

Comment: Thank you! I will do better. Just to be sure, a project would either be owned by an organization OR a user. So either field is 0. Wouldn't the first LEFT JOIN not return an empty table to the second LEFT JOIN if user_id is 0?

Comment: @DanielStephens . . . The tables were in the wrong order.  It was unclear which table has the owner fields.

Comment: Thank you! That helped me a lot!